# Ordering of pList Files

Tags: iphone, plist

I am reading in a pList file that I created.  It has a list of categories in it and it reads in each one and creates a button to represent that category.  The names are:

cHelp, cFun, cReading-Class

I would prefer that the order in the plist file is kept.  But instead I get cReading-Class first, cHelp second, and cFun last.

In the file they are listed has cHelp, cFun, cReading-Class.

Why does this happen?  Is there a way to control the order?  Modifing the order in the plist doesn't help.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Please post code to show how you read the property list file and also clarify if you are talking about the button order being wrong or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about you have a plist file that contains a dictionary of category (which itself is a dictionary)? If it is a dictionary, it should have no order, if it is an NSArray, there should have an order. Double check for that

Comment: So if it's a dictionary there is no way to easily have it read in the categories in order.  Or are you saying, make the overall container an array so it reads in order, then I can do what I want inside each item?